# How to read from api base project via browser in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, api

I can use my api base project from Insomnia or Postman but when I want to use it via web and browser where should I insert Auth Key or Token?

This is my Controller codes:

```
public function show_user_list()
{
    return response()->json(User::all(), 200);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@show_user_list')->name('show_user_list');
});
```

and when I want to use it via web and browser where should I insert Auth Key or Token?

I really mean I created an api base project and I developed it and now I want use my project's front-end with laravel itself view and blade as api.

What should I do?

Comment: You should read about what is an api and a frontend application.

Comment: @EliasSoares are you implying that frontend apps should not access apis? There may be multiple use cases where there is a requirement of an API as well as a user interface (that uses the API). I find it perfectly valid

Comment: No, I'm saying that he dont know what is an api. He developed an api using laravel passport and now is trying to use it with blade?!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Laravel Passport to consume your own API without worrying too much about the token:

```
composer require laravel/passport
add Passport::ignoreMigrations as per documentation
php artisan passport:install
add CreateFreshApiToken middleware
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

If you're using JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function ($) {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
          }
      });
      });
</script>
```

If you're using VueJs, everything is set in place

If you still want to use the TokenGuard, then you have to implement Passport's work: to pass and access the api token in a secure manner from frontend to backend, back and forth

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Alex's answer, if you'd like to use the built-in `token` guard, all you have to do is add an `api_token` column to your users table like so:

```
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique()->nullable()->default(null);
```

That's it. Now you can just use the `auth:api` middleware and send the token through either a) in the request body as `api_token`, or 2) in the `bearer token` header or 3) in the `PHP_AUTH_PW` header.

If you want to generate an api token, simply add a method that generates a unique one for each user like so:

```
public function generateApiKey(){
   do {
      $this->api_token = str_random(60);
   } while($this->where('api_token', $this->api_token)->exists());
   $this->save();
}
```

or alternatively you may also use [`Str::orderedUuid`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-ordered-uuid)

That's it. `Passport` is better than the `token` guard because in the `token` guard, the API token is pretty much stored as plain text with no expiry in the database which could be insecure. But if your use case requires simplicity, this may be the way to go